# Access an OpenGL texture as a CIImage

Tags: objective-c, xcode, opengl, unity-game-engine

I am trying to pass a reference of a cameras texture into xcode so that I can then use it for face detection. Most methods I have tried have left me stumped, but I think I am close with what I currently have.

In unity I get the texture id and pass this through a plugin:

```
[DllImport("__Internal")]

public static extern void SendBackground(int id, int width, int height);



//in Update

Texture bg_Img = GetComponentInChildren<VideoTextureBehaviour>().GetTexture(); //this is from Vuforia

int texture_Id = bg_Img.GetNativeTextureID();

SendBackground(texture_Id, bg_Img.width, bg_Img.height);
```

xcode receives the texture ID fine, I then try to access it from OpenGL and get it to a CIImage

```
- (void) DetectFaces:(int)tex_id :(int)width :(int)height

{

    glGenTextures(1, (GLuint)&tex_id);

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, (GLuint)tex_id);



    CIImage *image = [[CIImage alloc]  initWithTexture:(GLuint)tex_id size:CGSizeMake(width, height) flipped:YES colorSpace: (CGColorSpaceRef) kCGColorSpaceModelRGB];

}
```

Currently that last line results in a bad access exception at run time. I need to get the texture to CIImage so that I can then use the iOS native CIDetector code on it.

Comment: Actually I don't understand why your code tries to create a texture (glGenTextures) while you say you pass the texture ID from Unity... are you sure about this?

Answer (score 1):

There is a problem with your colorspace, you're passing a CGColorSpaceModel when a CGColorSpaceRef is required.

Try this instead:

```
CGColorSpaceRef cs = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
CIImage *image = [[CIImage alloc]  initWithTexture:(GLuint)tex_id size:CGSizeMake(width, height) flipped:YES colorSpace:(CGColorSpaceRef)kCGColorSpaceModelRGB];
...
CGColorSpaceRelease(cs); // Release the color space when you no longer need it
```

There might be other issues though but that seemed definitely incorrect to me.